# How can I duplicate my Linux C environment in Windows with CLION?

Tags: c, gcc, clion

I've been coding (C) directly in my production environment for a casual game I'm hacking together. The environment is:

> - No LSB modules are available.
> - Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> - Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
> - Release:        16.04
> - Codename:       xenial

The GCC version I've been using is as followed:

> gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609

My Windows environment that I want to make my development environment is:

> Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, Intel

So, I'm not an expert on duplicating this for gcc or with C. I have CLION, which does support both C and C++, but pretty much everything out there is tailored for C++ or Visual C++ or whatever. I feel a bit outdated, but want to get a working environment so I can actually compile outside of directly in the shell.

As it stands, I use CLION to do everything, but upload the source files to the shell and then compile. I have tried to install CMake with MinGW, but have failed. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is your C code 100% platform agnostic/generic (TBH, I've rarely ever seen C code that is really generic)? If not, what I would suggest is you just use a Linux VM on your local machine, it would make things WAY simpler and easier to test as it would be closer to your real "prod" environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not. I think this is why Cygwin is failing because it's still porting over Window based libraries. What options are their for duplicating Ubuntu on my Windows machine these days? My production environment is on AWS and don't want to pay for another.

Comment: I'd just install VMWarePlayer (I think the base player is still free) and create an Ubuntu image that resembles your AWS one as closely as possible same version, same packages, ...). By doing that, you can probably share a folder between your host and VM OS and use your IDE in your native OS then just compile/run in the VM.

Comment: What *parts* of Ubuntu do you need on Windows? Some of them are already there: [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I duplicate my Linux C environment in Windows with CLION?

Since you are developing a game, which requires much more than what the standard C11 programming language defines (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) **you probably cannot**.

The simplest approach is to **install Linux on your laptop** (perhaps in some VM).

Alternatively, perhaps the fellow members of your game project are all using some particular toolkit which happens to be ported to Windows (e.g. [SDL](https://libsdl.org/), [Qt](http://qt.io/), etc...). Then you might try using it.

Notice that [CLION](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) is not a compiler but an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (it uses an *external* compiler, perhaps GCC disguised as MinGW).

BTW, even on Windows (and of course on Linux also) you can (and probably should, at first) compile on the command line. You might want to use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool.

Comment: Don't make assumptions about the game. It's text-based (MUD). ;)

Comment: That should go into your question. Is it using [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) ?

Comment: No, it's coded in C. Multi-User Dungeons (MUDS) is basically what Massively Multiplayer Online Role-playing (MMORPG) games are today, without the rendering and sound engines. Essentially, the source code I'm using has been around since the 80's. You can check out the source code to what I'm using here. http://www.mudbytes.net/files/download/2849

Comment: `ncurses` is a C library to handle the terminal

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that's for text-based user interface development. This game does not use those. It's all command controlled with no interface.